# Error claims a protocol is a generic type, but no generics are used

Tags: swift, generics, compiler-errors, swift-extensions

I am wishing to implement a pattern similar to `Notification.Name` where anyone can add one later via an `extension`, like this:

### Swift 4

```swift
public protocol Foo {
    var bar: String { get }
}



public struct FooImpl: Foo {
    public let bar: String
}



public extension Foo {
    public static let baz: Foo = FooImpl(bar: "baz")
}

// Ideal usage:
someFuncThatTakesAFoo(.baz)
```

This seems fine to me, but I get a confusing error when compiling:

```
/path/to/main.swift:24:23: error: static stored properties not supported in generic types
    public static let baz: Foo = FooImpl(bar: "baz")
           ~~~~~~     ^
```

What's going on here, and what's a solution?

Comment: Compare: [Extension may not contain stored property but why is static allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45467329/2976878). I do agree the diagnostic isn't great in this case.

Comment: Related Swift bug: [SR-5856](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5856)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a weird error message, but your code shouldn't compile anyways. Stored properties are not supported in extensions, hence the error.

By removing the `static` keyword and just leaving `baz` as a stored property, you get a meaningful error:

> extensions may not contain stored properties

Changing the declaration to a computed property (and hence declaring it mutable) the error magically disappears.

```
public protocol Foo {
    var bar: String { get }
}

public struct FooImpl: Foo {
    public let bar: String
}


public extension Foo {
    public static var baz: Foo {
        return FooImpl(bar: "baz")
    }
}
```

Comment: But this works just fine: `extension FooImpl { static let baz = FooImpl(bar: "baz") }`. Like I said, this is a common practice in Swift, notably used in `Notification.Name` to allow semantic creation and use of object instances with the dot-prefix syntax

Comment: Also, when I try to use this solution like `let x = Foo.baz`, I get a new confusing error: `Static member 'baz' cannot be used on protocol metatype 'Foo.Protocol'`

Comment: [Here](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59b063c0d52b657e47709c8b) you can actually try running the code, it compiled with no problem. Also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38885813/4667835) answer, which also explains that you cannot have stored properties in protocol extensions. Moreover, the example in your comment is not the same as the one in the question, the comment one is a struct extension, while the question one is a protocol extension.

Comment: The error I described is there: http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59b153ef0e5da9521fbd03df

Comment: Well, that shouldn't work. A protocol on its own doesn't exist. `let x = FooImpl.baz` is valid, `let Foo.baz` is not.

Comment: A protocol doesn't exist? I'm not sure what you're saying. Also the example in my comment is the usage site of the problem in my question. I'll edit it to reflect that.

Comment: A protocol is an abstract type. There is no such thing as an instance of a protocol and hence your code cannot compile. You can implement classes that conform to the protocol and those classes can have instances and hence access functions/computed properties that are part of the protocol. Have a look into protocols in Swift, it seems you have a big misunderstanding about what they are and how they work.

Comment: @DávidPástor I get what you're saying, and I agree at runtime that's true. Still, `Foo.baz` is just syntax and the compiler should be able to work out what I want to do. Perhaps it creates a new uniquely-named global variable, perhaps something I can't imagine. It just doesn't seem so unreasonable that it's still not possible in version 4.0.